# can't fix mesh texture does anyone have a sloution?

Tags: mesh, uv, uv-image-editor

the texture on my object looks great and it's exactly what I want but the problem is the top of the mesh is so stretched and I tried everything to fix it but with no luck
I think the main reason why there are no vertexes on the top so how to add vertexes?
[image][image]

[image]

[image]

https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/AswVrpBm

Comment: Hello :). Please attach a wireframe view of the top of your mesh. There obviously *are* vertices, but perhaps the topology could be improved.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116925/how-to-make-textures-follow-a-certain-path

Comment: @JachymMichal i added new pics

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is select the top faces, select one to make it active, unwrap with the *Follow Active Quads* option:

[image]

Then move the UVs so that the bricks match each other:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer but the problem is i can't even add faces on the top :(

Comment: why that? please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/AswVrpBm

Comment: i made new one because the original file was like 300 MB and it took forever to upload

Comment: you have a solidify modifier, you need to apply it, but before that, disable it and remove the top and bottom faces of your cylinder