# Blender 2.8 equivalent of UV Squares / make islands straight?

Tags: uv

I'm starting to use Blender 2.8 beta and have a question :
Is there something like UV Squares that I could use to make my UV islands straight ? I already tried with pins, didn't worked.
Thank you ! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get perfect UV sphere Mercator projection?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/how-to-get-perfect-uv-sphere-mercator-projection)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78358/how-to-straighten-curved-uvs-into-straight-belt/78376#78376

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perfectly align UV coordinates automatically?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74041/how-to-perfectly-align-uv-coordinates-automatically)