# How to UV Unwrap in straight lines?

Tags: modeling, mesh, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm struggling to <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + Select those side faces, but when I manage it and try to unwrap, it creates a curved UV, which is not what I'm trying to do.

So how do I unwrap these into straight UVs ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74041/how-to-perfectly-align-uv-coordinates-automatically/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78358/how-to-straighten-curved-uvs-into-straight-belt/

Comment: you could mark a vertical seam on one of the edges, then unwrap, or as Duarte suggests, use the Follow Active Quads (but I guess it doesn't keep the faces proportions so you'll have to scale).