# Stuggling to UV Wrap Can

Tags: uv

I am trying to UV Wrap the can in the image but I am struggling with how to design my label so it fits the correct curve of the UV map.

I tried warping my image in Photoshop but I just couldn't make it look prefect. Is there an easier way in Blender?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74041/how-to-perfectly-align-uv-coordinates-automatically/74045#74045 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78358/how-to-straighten-curved-uvs-into-straight-belt/78376#78376

Answer (score 2):

You can use UV>Cylinder Projection with your surface faces selected. Just make sure you don't select the bulging parts on top and bottom. They have to be mapped seperately, as well as the top and bottom caps. (Don't use Live Unwrap to avoid your UVs getting messed up)

[image]

BTW: If you don't want to deform your can later on, you can save a lot of geometry in your model (and even then, you can always add more geometry later, while it's more time consuming to remove unwanted geometry). 
You don't need any of the edge rings between the two shape defining ones at the top and bottom. It's always good to keep the polycount low, be it for vfx or games.

[image]