# Apply image texture to very long object

Tags: texturing, objects, image

I need to apply an image texture of an Armco barrier (guardrail) to a very long, flat-plane  object in blender model.
I don't know how to unwrap such a long object on to an image texture.  The image texture is perhaps 5 feet but the Armco is, e.g., 500 feet.  I believe there is a way to have a texture image repeat along the object but I can't figure out how to execute this.  I only understand the very basics of UV unwrap, materials and textures so detailed explanation would be most appreciated
Thank you.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78358/how-to-straighten-curved-uvs-into-straight-belt/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74041/how-to-perfectly-align-uv-coordinates-automatically

Answer (score 0):

When UV unwrapping, space outside the 0,1 range is mapped back onto the texture as if with a modulo operator.

To help with the visualization you can check view->Repeat Image

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I don't understand "outside the 0,1 range".  When I unwrap the guardrail, which is much longer than the image texture, where should the long UV map be placed relative to the not-so-long image texture?

Comment: You can scale your UVs outside of the default square area. These UV coordinates are expressed between 0 and 1, as left/bottom side of the square for 0 and right/top side for 1.
Did you enable Repeat Image ?