# Is there a way to scale uvs based on fabric stretch

Tags: uv

I am making a stuffed animal. My goal is to have the grain of the fabric follow a cats hair direction, and to account for the stretch in the fabric. I need the uvs to be proportionate to the model in order to use them for a sewing pattern. I was wondering if there is a way to unwrap uvs to keep them proportionate, while not scattering the islands, so then I can then scale the uvs to match the stretch of the fabric I will be using. I was following [seams to sewing pattern](http://thomaskole.nl/s2s/), but they don't account for stretch. My other option currently is to rotate and place the islands in Inkscape, which I would prefer not to do. Thanks in advance!

Direction of the grain the fabric will follow, and showing scattering of islands:
[image]

What I would like to have (so the pattern is stretched in unison):
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74041/how-to-perfectly-align-uv-coordinates-automatically/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78358/how-to-straighten-curved-uvs-into-straight-belt/

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks for answering so quickly. The solutions that you linked don't do what I was hoping for. The 'unwrap' option works fine for proportions, but I was hoping that there was a way to have the islands close to their original position on the model. Is there a way for the islands to be less scattered in their placement in the uv map?